# Fastest way to skin a grid

Tags: python, mesh, numpy

Having recently answered a question re the Z surface math function, from the add mesh extras addon, made me get back to coding same via `numpy` for instance with a  [numpy meshgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64450589/5317130).

For example, to create a 4 x 5 vertices grid in blender, the grid's vertex indices would, from top view,  look like

```
import numpy as np
rows = 5
cols = 4

A = np.flip(np.arange(rows * cols).reshape((-1, cols)), 0)


[[16 17 18 19]
 [12 13 14 15]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 0  1  2  3]]
```

and then to skin the thing would make each face by winding CCW over each 2 x 2 quad

eg indices of some of the 12 faces

```
(0, 1, 5, 4)
(1, 2, 6, 5)
(2, 3, 7, 6)
...
(9, 10, 14, 13)
(10, 11, 15, 14)
```

and pass this to `Mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)`

All good, very quick, however, always feel there is a faster more numpy-centric way to generate the quad face indices.

[Extract blocks or patches from NumPy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527755/extract-blocks-or-patches-from-numpy-array)

[Reverse even rows in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280681/reverse-even-rows-in-a-numpy-array-or-pandas-dataframe)

The question: given `rows x cols` vertices, what is the quickest way to create the `faces`?

Comment: geometry nodes! :D

Comment: I can already feel a great self answer coming

Comment: i can smell that too....! i just wonder why it takes so long....

Comment: Interesting problem. I'm not a numpy guy, no idea if my observations are useful at all, but vertex indices repeat (each appears up to 4 times), therefore simply reshaping the array is not going to work - but duplicating it 4 times and then reshaping and then intertwining (zipping) could work... And getting the CCW would be about reversing odd columns with even columns on odd rows...

Comment: Maybe using a 1d array instead of 2d array ? Btw, look like rows and cols are inverted ?

Comment: np.linspace + np.delete unwanted faces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using numpy 'only', in order to avoid Python iterations, that can be:

- Generate all faces with an extra face for each row, using `np.linspace`.
- Reshape to place the last face of each row as last element (in second dimension)
- Delete the last column
- Reshape again to obtain the result

Sample code (I've done no performance tests):

```
import numpy as np

# Example
rows = 3
cols = 5
# 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
#  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
#  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,

# first_face = [0, 1, 6, 5]
first_face = [0, 1, cols + 1, cols]

# Last face index is on the top right
last_face_index = cols * (rows - 1)

# last_face = [9, 10, 15, 14]
last_face = [i + last_face_index - 1 for i in first_face]

# Generates all faces with an extra face per row (at the end of each row)
# by linear interpolation
faces = np.linspace(first_face, last_face, last_face_index)

# Deletes extra faces that are on the right
# Result is rows - 1, all cols and 4 vertices
faces = np.reshape(faces, (rows - 1, cols, 4))
# Remove the last col considering second axis
faces = np.delete(faces, cols - 1, 1)
# Final result is arrays of 4 indices
faces = np.reshape(faces, (-1, 4))

print(faces)
print(len(faces))
```

Alternatively, you can also use several `np.linspace` to define:

- The first row (or column)
- The last row (or column)
- Interpolate between them

Answer (score 6):

**Test Results.**

*Big thanks to @lemon. The original thought behind this question was toward making a grid via numpy as fast as possible.*

Test Script to add a grid using numpy, bmesh operator and operator.

For trivial sizes 10 x 10 numpy is well ahead, by 100 x 100 it is well, last. Cursory investigation shows `mesh.from_pydata` in script below, is the rate determining step.

Points toward using a hybrid method to create the grid with `bmesh` then manipulate later with `numpy` using `foreach_get` and `foreach_set`

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
import bmesh
from time import time
from bpy import context

def to_object(name, me):
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(name, me)
    context.collection.objects.link(ob)
    return ob

def bmesh_grid(rows, cols):
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new("BMGrid")
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bmesh.ops.create_grid(
            bm,
            x_segments=cols,
            y_segments=rows,
            )
    bm.to_mesh(me)
            

def np_grid(rows, cols):

    m = np.dstack(
        np.meshgrid(
            np.linspace(-1, 1, cols),
            np.linspace(-1, 1, rows),
            )
        ).reshape(-1, 2)
    verts = np.dstack(
        [m[:,0], 
        m[:, 1], 
        np.zeros(rows * cols)]
        ).reshape(-1, 3)

    # skinning code courtesy of @lemon
    first_face = [0, 1, cols + 1, cols]
    last_face_index = cols  * (rows - 1)
    last_face = [i + last_face_index - 1 for i in first_face]
    faces = np.linspace(first_face, last_face, last_face_index)
    
    #faces = faces[np.mod(np.arange(last_face_index), cols) > 0]
    faces = np.reshape(faces, (rows - 1, cols, 4))
    faces = np.delete(faces, cols - 1, 1)
    faces = np.reshape(faces, (-1, 4))
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new("NPGrid")
    #https://developer.blender.org/T90268    
    me.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
    # pre fix
    #me.from_pydata(verts, [], list(faces))
    to_object("NPGrid", me)  


# test call

rows, cols = 500, 100


t = time()
bmesh_grid(rows, cols)
bm_time = time() - t
print("BM", bm_time)

t = time()

np_grid(rows, cols)
np_time = time() - t
print("NP", np_time)

t = time()
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_grid_add(
    x_subdivisions=cols,
    y_subdivisions=rows,
    )
op_time = time() - t
print("OP", op_time)

# ugly one liner to remove all add grids
#bpy.data.batch_remove([o for o in bpy.data.objects if any(o.name.startswith(k) for k in ("Grid", "NPGrid", "BMGrid"))])

print(f"{np_time / op_time :.3f}")
```

Comment: In Blender 3.2 had to switch '#me.from_pydata(verts, [], list(faces))' for 'me.from_pydata(verts.tolist(), [], faces.astype(int))'