# How can i connect those two points?

Tags: python, vertex-groups

The following code is a copy from [Add a simple vertex via python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23088/31447):

```
import bpy

def point_cloud(ob_name, coords, edges=[], faces=[]):
    """Create point cloud object based on given coordinates and name.

    Keyword arguments:
    ob_name -- new object name
    coords -- float triplets eg: [(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0), (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)]
    """

    # Create new mesh and a new object
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new(ob_name + "Mesh")
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(ob_name, me)

    # Make a mesh from a list of vertices/edges/faces
    me.from_pydata(coords, edges, faces)

    # Display name and update the mesh
    ob.show_name = True
    me.update()
    return ob

# Create the object
pc = point_cloud(".", [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),(0.1,0.1,0.1)])


# Link object to the active collection
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(pc)
```

Comment: pass `edges=((0, 1))` to create an edge from vert 0 to vert 1  Could you please post a link to  script source  if you sill have it.

Comment: My question:

In Input textbox, the user will be putting a configuration which will look something like this .


2-(90),5-(0),4-(-90).

This above configuration means :

Create a Line of
2 units in 90 degrees, 5 units in 0 degrees direction, and lastly, 4 units in -90 degrees.


As a submit button is pressed your script should create lines in z-plane as shown.

The top view will look something like this 
https://i.imgur.com/0GETSLY.jpg

Comment: Coincidentally [answered that yesterday](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234784/how-to-access-the-user-input-from-a-dialog-box-and-also-how-to-change-it-from-st)

Comment: There are many code which is the correct code of the question can you share the correct code?