# Why does this script crash the latest version of Blender?

Tags: text-object

I run this code in Scripting, making sure that no meshes are selected. Blender freezes and hangs before any error messages are generated.

What is going wrong with the script?

```
import bpy

# Ask the user for text
text = input("Enter text: ")

# Set the text and font
bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(0, 0, 0))
text_object = bpy.context.active_object
text_object.data.body = text
text_object.data.font = bpy.data.fonts["Arial"]

# Set the dimensions of the text
bpy.context.object.dimensions = (text_object.dimensions[0], 10, 0.2)

# Set the material of the text to metallic
text_object.active_material = bpy.data.materials.new("Metallic Material")
text_object.active_material.use_nodes = True
node_tree = text_object.active_material.node_tree
node_tree.nodes.clear()

# Add a principled BSDF node
principled_bsdf = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled")
principled_bsdf.inputs['Roughness'].default_value = 0.1
principled_bsdf.inputs['Metallic'].default_value = 1
node_tree.links.new(principled_bsdf.outputs['BSDF'], node_tree.nodes['Material Output'].inputs['Surface'])

# Add a light source
bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='POINT', location=(-1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='POINT', location=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='POINT', location=(0, 0, 1))
```

Comment: did you get a *crash.txt file in C:\Users[login]\AppData\Local\Temp?  You may want to paste a few lines near the top into your post.  If a crash file, consider submitting a Bug Report via the Help >> BugReport menu item.

Answer (score 1):

Your script **freezes Blender because you ask the user to enter a value in the System Console window**. This is not a good idea because this window can be hidden (*File > Window > Toggle System Console*) and Mac users don't have this menu entry at all. If the System Console window is hidden you can't enter a value and because the script blocks the UI you cannot make the window visible. Deadlock.

Better use Blender's user interface (UI) to get values from the user. Here is a similar question with an example: [How to access the User input from a dialog box and also how to change it from String to Float? I am new to Python Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/234784/107598)

Furthermore, your script has a few flaws and issues.

- 'Arial' is a font on Windows systems, but actually, it's four fonts: normal (regular), **bold**, *italic*, ***bold & italic***. So you need to choose one of these not just 'Arial'.
- the font must be loaded first before you can use it. I don't know how you can script this. But once you have selected a font and it is loaded you can use it in the script.
  [image: font selection]
- the *Material Output* node is missing
- the shader nodes are created overlapping
- there is no `bpy.ops.object.lamp_add()` but `bpy.ops.object.light_add()`

Putting it all together, you can create an operator from your script that allows the user to enter the text.

Once you run the script, you can search for the operator with <kbd>F3</kbd> or main menu *Edit > Menu Search...*. Search for `object.simple_text_operator ▶Simple Text Operator` (screenshot is not up to date).

[image: search operator screenshot]

On the first run, you will get a 'Hello World!' text and you can change the text in the *Adjust Last Operation* popup that appears in the bottom left corner. Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to bring it back if you dismissed it and have not done another operation yet.

[image: hello world! screenshot]

```py
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty

def main(context, text):
    
    # use default text if no text is entered
    if len(text) == 0:
        text = 'Hello World!'   
    
    # Set the text and font
    bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(0, 0, 0))
    text_object = bpy.context.active_object
    text_object.data.body = text
    text_object.data.font = bpy.data.fonts["Arial Black"]    #  font must be loaded 

    # Set the dimensions of the text
    bpy.context.object.dimensions = (text_object.dimensions[0], 10, 0.2)

    # Set the material of the text to metallic
    text_object.active_material = bpy.data.materials.new("Metallic Material")
    text_object.active_material.use_nodes = True
    node_tree = text_object.active_material.node_tree
    node_tree.nodes.clear()

    # Add Material Output
    material_output_node = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeOutputMaterial")

    # Add a principled BSDF node
    principled_bsdf = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled")
    principled_bsdf.inputs['Roughness'].default_value = 0.1
    principled_bsdf.inputs['Metallic'].default_value = 1
    node_tree.links.new(principled_bsdf.outputs['BSDF'], node_tree.nodes['Material Output'].inputs['Surface'])

    # move the BSDF node so it doesn't hide the material output node
    principled_bsdf.location.x -= 300     

    # Add a light source
    bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='POINT', location=(-1, 1, 1))
    bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='POINT', location=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='POINT', location=(0, 0, 1))


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_text_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Text Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    mytext : StringProperty(name="Text")

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context, self.mytext)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```